# Fetching only the soft deleted records

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.3

i have created a method to fetch only the soft deleted lessons in my LessonsController

i'm not getting what should be the route my lessoncontroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Response;
use App\lesson;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class LessonsController extends ApiController 
{

    protected $lessonTransformer;

    function __construct(LessonTransformer $lessonTransformer) 
    {
        $this->lessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;
    }

    //fetch all and pass a metadata 'data' 
    public function index() 
    {
        $lessons = Lesson::all();

        return $this->respond([
            'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transformCollection($lessons->all())
        ]);
    }

    //delete a lesson by id
    public function destroy($id)
    {   
        $dlesson = Lesson::find(input::get('id'));

        if(! $dlesson) {
            return $this->respondNotFound();
        }

        $dlesson->delete();

        return $this->respondDeleted('Lesson deleted successfully');
    }

    public function deletedLessons() 
    {
        $deleted_lessons = Lesson::onlyTrashed()->get();

        return $this->respond([
            'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transformCollection($lessons->all())
        ]);
    }    

}
```

i have tried with a deleted record like 
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/lessons/11

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Make sure:

- You've used `softDeletes()` method in migration and executed this migration
- You're using `SoftDeletes` trait in the model
- You've added `deleted_at` to `$dates` property in the model

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting

After doing all that your query will work just fine and will return only soft deleted lessons:

```
$deleted_lessons = Lesson::onlyTrashed()->get();
```

Comment: i have did all of that, if i replace the `index()` to `Lesson::all()` to `Lesson::onlyTrashed()->get();` i'm able to get the result but how do i fetch in a separate method rather in `index() `

Comment: Are you saying that exactly the same code works in `index()` but doesn't work in other methods?

Comment: yes, i doubt that the route is not proper if the get api/v1/lessons i'll get all the lesson expect deleted one which is fine but to get deleted lessons which route i should

Comment: Check result of `dd(Lesson::onlyTrashed()->get());` in `index()` and some other method. I'm sure it will return the same result. If result is the same, the problem is somewhere else. Maybe problem is in transformation methods.